# Custom field in detailed transaction report

Tags: paypal

I'm currently sending an ID in the 'custom' field with the payment request data:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="paymentForm">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_ext-enter">
                        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_cmd" value="_xclick">
                        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@xxx.it">
                        .... 
OTHER FIELDS
                                                .....
                        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="#websiteID#">
                        <input type="submit" name="sub" />
                    </form>
```

I need to retrieve that ID in one of the columns of the detailed transaction report (I'm italian: 'Cronologia > Report > transazioni dettagliate).

I do the same for Express Checkout, using the field `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM`.

I don't know where to expect it in the report, and I cannot distinguish it by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you provide in the `CUSTOM` field (of any of the PayPal APIs) is not stored in the transaction details. You cannot retrieve this information as it is more of a custom pass-through.

It will be in the PDT or IPN responses, but not in any transaction report you can download from PayPal. If you need this information after the transaction is complete you need to save it in your own database, or store the ID in another field that does get saved by PayPal. (`PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC`, `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTETEXT`, etc)

Comment: what is the equivalent of PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/ ? My shopping cart allows both "classic" checkout via form and express checkout.

Comment: what about using item number or item name?

Comment: Answer is correct, but the custom field IS saved by PayPal and is visible if you view the transaction after clicking "See details on classic site". Sucks that they don't pass it through.